# ajax loading suddenly not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I loaded a div using ajax and it worked perfectly till yesterday when I put my hands on a couple of lines in code

and suddenly it doesn't load any contents for some reason.

```
jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.open_list', function() {
    jQuery('.list').addClass('slideIn');
})

jQuery(document.body).on('click', '.open_list', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    jQuery(".ajax_list").fadeOut(function() {

        var $ajaxList = jQuery(this);

        $ajaxList.load("http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/free .ajax_contents", function() {
            $ajaxList.fadeIn();
        });
    });
});
```

literally, if i click on the 'click me' button ajax loads contents.

am i doing this in a wrong way?

http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/xe/

Comment: Do you see any error message in the console? (The code you posted here has a syntax error.)

Comment: Why the wrapping click event handler? Also there are some remains of a comment in line 1 `*/`.

Comment: No, i have not recieved any console errors, and i deleted the comment */

Comment: this code was helped by many other people, and i do not know what is 'wrapping click event handler' is but ' jQuery('.open_list').click(function() { 'had collided with 'TweenMax.to(".board_contents", 0.5, {opacity:1, top:200, ease:Back.easeInOut}); ' that's why i used the code above.

Comment: @Mark What I mean is, you add an event handler to `.open_list` and on click you attach another 2 delegated event handlers on that same class. Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I run your page and click on the button, I get this in the console:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://dothome.co.kr/expiration/404.html.
>   No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr' is therefore not
>   allowed access.

And, in fact if you just try to load the URL `http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/free`, in the browser you will get a 404 not found error.  So, apparently the page `http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/free` is not there which is what your ajax call is trying to load.

Comment: my bad. i should have double checked the address. http://lifeto.dothome.co.kr/xe/ now works perfectly. thanks.

Comment: @Mark - you should also look in the console AFTER you click on the button.  That's where I saw this error.

Answer (score 0):

The page you tried to load has a 404 error message (file doesn't exist).
The 404 page has a header (a piece of data sent with the page), called `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`, which didn't allow request from another origin (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10636611/how-does-access-control-allow-origin-header-work)).
Since your page is located under http://life.dothome.co.kr while the 404 page you requested is under http://dothome.co.kr, it cannot load the file.
Fix the page url and you should be fine.

Comment: thanks for the quick and near perfect answer. but someone has already answered 30 secs ago. sorry but appreciate your answer.